# How do I do a clean install of Mountain Lion with no disc?

Tags: macos, install

I purchased an iMac in late 2013. This model has no disc drive. It came with Mountain Lion pre-installed. If I ever needed to perform a clean install of Mountain Lion, how can I? I don't have an installer file and no disc came with the computer. What's the official way to deal with the fact that I essentially don't own a copy of the OS my computer came with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Repairs/Recovery:

One is to use the build in recovery installed on your hard drive. To check for it use disk utility, but it is a hidden partition so make it non hidden first.

Second one is to use the Internet Recovery.

For clean install:

is to [create a bootable USB](http://macs.about.com/od/macoperatingsystems/ss/Create-Bootable-Copies-Of-The-Os-X-Mountain-Lion-Installer.htm), with complete ML installer. (you need to have/[purchase](http://store.apple.com/us/product/D6377Z/A/os-x-mountain-lion) the ML installer package), and a USB with 8GB space.

http://macs.about.com/od/usingyourmac/qt/How-To-Re-Download-Apps-From-The-Mac-App-Store.htm

Example:

[OS X Recovery Disk Assistant v1.0](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1433)

> The OS X Recovery Disk Assistant lets you create OS X Recovery on an
>   external drive that has all of the same capabilities as the built-in
>   OS X Recovery: reinstall Lion or later, repair the disk using Disk
>   Utility, restore from a Time Machine backup, or browse the web with
>   Safari.
>
> Note: In order to create an external OS X  Recovery using the OS X
>   Recovery Assistant, the Mac must have an existing Recovery HD.
>
> To create an external OS X Recovery, download the OS X Recovery Disk
>   Assistant application. Insert an external drive, launch the OS X 
>   Recovery Disk Assistant,  select the drive where you would like to
>   install, and follow the on screen instructions.

Comment: My wife purchased a Mountain Lion upgrade from the App Store and we created a USB installer from that. Can I use that on my computer, or is it copy protected and tied to her computer?

Comment: It is a universal installer. No copy protection.